# Como comprimir vídeo no upload utilizando PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, algoritmo, compressão

Possuo uma aplicação onde é possível fazer upload de vídeos, e ao fazer o upload do vídeo na aplicação, eu necessito comprimir o mesmo, antes que seja salvo no banco de dados. 
Estou precisando comprimir vídeos antes que seja feito upload na minha aplicação, pois subir videos de 50MB não seria algo viável. Existe alguma alternativa quanto a isso? procurei por libs JS que pudessem fazer isso mas não cheguei em nenhuma

Comment: Boa tarde, já pensou em hospedar no VIMEO ou Youtube? Desconheço outro forma de diminuir a resolução a não ser renderizar novamente em um formato para web.

Comment: A questão é que se trata de upload de usuário, então não seria possível assim :/

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse serviço, talvez resolva... uso ele para fotos.. mas nunca usei para vídeos.

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/video_manipulation_and_delivery

Comment: Você está utilizando algum backend, como por exemplo o NodeJS? Ou somente frontend com HTML, CSS e Javascript puro?

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS to usando CodeIgniter

Comment: @GustavoFritola, o CodeIgniter é um Framework para PHP. Então você está utilizando o PHP no seu backend.

Comment: sim sim @THIAGODEBONIS, esqueci de citar isso. Conhece algo que poderia ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em **PHP NATIVO** ***não existe nada relacionado sobre***. Mas você pode utilizar uma **biblioteca** denominada [PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg).

**PHP-FFMpeg**

> É uma **biblioteca orientada a objetos** para **converter arquivos de vídeo/áudio** com o **FFmpeg/AVConv**. Esta **biblioteca** requer uma instalação do **FFMpeg** em funcionamento. Você precisará dos **binários FFMpeg e FFProbe** para usá-lo. **Certifique-se** de que **esses binários** podem ser **localizados** com o **PATH** do **sistema** para **obter o benefício da detecção binária**, ***caso contrário***, ***você deverá fornecer explicitamente o caminho dos binários no carregamento***.

**Mais informações você pode acessar o** [repositório oficial da biblioteca](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg).